# Is there an NHibernate event you can register for which fires on lazy load

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lazy-loading

When my server is run in some debug mode, I'd be interested in logging lazy loads (whether it be that a foreign key was exercised or whether it be that a child collection was loaded).  Anyone aware of whether NHibernate exposes such an event?

Edit: I don't just want to enable nhibernate log4net logging (which I currently suppress below Warn), I'd actually like to catch an event so that I can process it as I wish.  For instance, at the end of a web service call where I log how long the web service call took, I may log some db statistics including number of lazy loads that occured during that call, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [NHProf](http://nhprof.com/)? It's should let profile how nHibernate is behaving and give you a good insight into how thigns are running.

**EDIT** See this question: [NHibernate for web app, count amount of lazy loading occurrences per request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861897/nhibernate-for-web-app-count-amount-of-lazy-loading-occurrences-per-request)

Comment: Indeed, I use NHProf pretty frequently.  But I'm still looking for this event.

Comment: Regarding your edit...  Thanks for pointing out that post.  But bummer, his solution is very crude.  The post is 5 years old, though, perhaps some new events have been added in that time.  I'll come back and update if I find something.

Comment: Welcome I didn't even look at the solution just saw it was the same essential question. Good luck let us know if you come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the `IInitializeCollectionEventListener` or overriding the `DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener`.  This fires during the lazy load of a collection.  At least it does the first time.  Not sure if it fires when the collection is loaded from cache or not.

Answer (score -1):

There are `pre-load` and `post-load` events...

Comment: I saw mention of them.  Can they tell you that the load is occuring as a result of a lazy load situation?

Comment: No, these do not fire for lazy loading.